# python3 communication between daemon thread and main

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, events, communication

I am new to python and looking for the right concept to communicate between an deamon thread and my main. The main starts the deamon thread.

The deamon thread reads the input of an barcode scanner from the file "/dev/hidraw0" and prints it. This works great.

Now I want to do something in my main every time the deamon thread detects an new intput.

Is it possible to trigger an event in the deamon thread and to handle the event in main?

I cant predict a new Scanner Input. So to wait for the tread is no option.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the [Event](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/threading.html#event-objects) sync object :)